# How to efficently setup my DynamoDb queries from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, networking, amazon-dynamodb

I have a pretty simple question so there are 2 types of coding practice i have considered

case 1:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports dop1 = async(params) =>{ 
    return docClient.query(params).promise(); 
}
exports dop2 = async(params) =>{ 
    return docClient.query(params).promise(); 
}
```

case 2:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    
exports dop1 = async(params) =>{ 
    const doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    return docClient.query(params).promise(); 
}
exports dop2 = async(params) =>{  
    const doClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    return docClient.query(params).promise(); 
}
```

So for the first instance i declare the doclient globally and reuse that object in each subsequent call where as in the second case i declare the doClient Object in each db operation which one is more efficient.

My hypothesis was the first one would have been way faster because it doesn't recreate the object saving time and also it using the same tcp connection under the hood just adding a HTTP call for each underlying dboperation but i assuming that is not true so i want to understand the entire picture here

Some Questions on My Mind:

0. which one is faster and why so, which should one use over the other.
1. how can I keep a TCP connection Open to DynamoDB like create a pool of TCP connections and use one of these to sent my HTTP request and how do I avoid creating a new TCP connection each time.
2. Does case2 actually open a new TCP connection to Dynamodb each time?
3. I understand sometimes my server might be flooded with a lot of requests and I can only handle a limited no of them because of the no of ephemeral ports on Linux so in such a case how can I dynamically close one of this TCP connection to reuse that port for a separate purpose

My understanding is very fuzzy and therefore would really appreciate an answer with much depth or reference on how to make these concepts clear

Answer (score 1):

1. Definitely a Global object, reusing the object is efficient.
2. Even with global object, we need to keep the http connection alive, to avoid closing and opening each time.

we need to use [keepAlive](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) http connection to

```
const agent = new https.Agent({
  keepAlive: true
});
```

By default [maxSockets](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) set to 256, when keepAlive is true, which probably is plenty. So, connections going beyond what no of ephemeral  ports OS can handle is probably out of question.

Something like this:

```
import { Agent as httpsAgent } from 'https';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
var docClient = new DB.DocumentClient({
    httpOptions: {
        connectTimeout: 4000,
        agent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
    },
    apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
    convertEmptyValues: true,
});
```

Comment: Can you add some metric as to how efficient one is over the other and which is a better practice in production level code. Also part 3 of the question.

Comment: I updated couple more links. and a per tests, I don't have the exact numbers, but tests performed with keepAlive did way better with AWS Lambdas than those without, a few years back. Ever since I just use keepAlive agent as standard.

Comment: defining a global object I cannot update the config for it each time right, like in my case for CASE 2 I could update AWS Config each time before constructing the docClient Object and hence I could access it using the newer config can I do something similar for the global declaration.

Comment: Ok. what is the config you are planning to update each time? I would declare entire docClient creation globally!

Comment: Like each time before using the docClient I want to set the region and endpoint for it to access